# Build .vcxproj on Linux using xbuild

Tags: c, linux, xbuild

I want to run a simple C script on Ubuntu like this:

```
xbuild HelloWorld.vcxproj
```

When I run the script, I get this error:

> HelloWorld.vcxproj: error :
>   /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d4407e37ceba8427/Hel‌​loWorld/HelloWorld.v‌​cxproj:
>   /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d4407e37ceba8427/Hel‌​loWorld/HelloWorld.v‌​cxproj
>   could not import "$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props"

This is the script:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

Comment: I've edited my question with the script

Comment: You might install latest Mono and use cross platform MSBuild instead of xbuild. But since Visual C++ was not yet ready for cross platform scenarios (VC++ 2017 might introduce that), you really should not try it out right now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project [GCCBuild](https://github.com/roozbehid/GCCBuild) which you can use to build vcxproj files in Linux. It simple uses same structure of vcxproj but uses GCC to compile and build. There are multiple examples there too.